# How do different browsers handle huge amount of same events?

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, dom-events

I'm trying to make a Drag'n'Drop with highlighting of a place where an item will be dropped.
When `onDragOver` event hits I do some calculations so basically these calculations are performed every time a user moves mouse pointer, because place of dropping also depends on the relative position of the pointer to the element over which pointer is being dragged.

The question is: what happens when next `onDragOver` is being called but the previous one is still calculating things?

Here is an example of my problem https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-njenrg

Basically I'm setting a class to an element over which another element is being dragged, and on `dragLeave` I remove the class.
I'm simulating some expensive calculations by doing this:

```
const arr = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
  arr.push(Math.pow(Math.random() * 100 + 1,100)); 
}
```

Try to move elements one over others for some time and you will notice that when you drop the item you still can see some elements have red border. It means that `dragLeave` wasn't executed for those elements.

I want to ask you if there is a way to cancel previous calculation if a new one starts, so `dragLeave` will be executed in time?

Comment: There's only a single thread which executes JS, and the same thread listens to events, hence you never can get an event fired before the previous was totally handled.

Comment: Does it mean that there is no way of fixing my issue but optimizing the calculations?

Comment: I  would like to help you, but you should **[create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**. If it will not work with SO snippets, then put it to https://codepen.io please.